# Apache HttpClient is running out of connection but I'm not sure why?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

After some usage, HttpClient seems to block here, causing my whole app to freeze:

```
Thread [main] (Suspended)   
    Unsafe.park(boolean, long) line: not available [native method]  
    LockSupport.park(Object) line: 186  
    AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await() line: 2043   
    AbstractConnPool$2(PoolEntryFuture<T>).await(Date) line: 131    
    HttpConnPool(AbstractConnPool<T,C,E>).getPoolEntryBlocking(T, Object, long, TimeUnit, PoolEntryFuture<E>) line: 281 
    AbstractConnPool<T,C,E>.access$000(AbstractConnPool, Object, Object, long, TimeUnit, PoolEntryFuture) line: 62  
    AbstractConnPool$2.getPoolEntry(long, TimeUnit) line: 176   
    AbstractConnPool$2.getPoolEntry(long, TimeUnit) line: 172   
    AbstractConnPool$2(PoolEntryFuture<T>).get(long, TimeUnit) line: 100    
    PoolingClientConnectionManager.leaseConnection(Future<HttpPoolEntry>, long, TimeUnit) line: 212 
    PoolingClientConnectionManager$1.getConnection(long, TimeUnit) line: 199    
    DefaultRequestDirector.execute(HttpHost, HttpRequest, HttpContext) line: 453    
    ContentEncodingHttpClient(AbstractHttpClient).execute(HttpHost, HttpRequest, HttpContext) line: 927 
    ContentEncodingHttpClient(AbstractHttpClient).execute(HttpUriRequest, HttpContext) line: 826    
    ContentEncodingHttpClient(AbstractHttpClient).execute(HttpUriRequest) line: 804 
    ...
```

I don't see any "close()" or "release()" method on the returned HttpResponse, what am I not doing here that I need to be doing?

Per request, here is my code:

```
final HttpResponse hr = Misc.httpClient.execute(hg);
if (hr.getEntity().getContentType().getValue().toLowerCase().contains("html")) {
    final Document doc = Jsoup.parse(hr.getEntity().getContent(), ContentType.getOrDefault(hr.getEntity()).getCharset(), urlAsString);
    processDocument(url, doc);
} else if (hr.getEntity().getContentType().getValue().toLowerCase().contains("text/xml")) {
    final SyndFeedInput input = new SyndFeedInput();

    rssFeed = input.build(new InputStreamReader(hr.getEntity().getContent()));
}
```

Comment: Show us your code, how you use the `HttpClient` API. For starters try using `execute()` with `ResponseHandler` parameter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `InputStream` that you get from your HttpResponse needs to have `close()` called on it. There's no `close()` for HttpResponse itself.

For example, when you get your HttpResponse and call `getEntity()` to get an HttpEntity, calling `getContent()` to get the InputStream, after you've done reading the content, call `close()` on the InputStream.

Answer (score 0):

More details would help but here are few reasons that things like this might happen:

1. You keep opening connections to the same server and expect the server to close them while the server expects you to reuse the connection (http1.1) so you actually have a leak.
2. You may have connectivity problem in the underlying transport (routing etc) that causes this, so the httpclient is waiting for TCP to timeout.
3. The server is keeping the connection open because it's busy but hasn't replied yet.